# Display some field from two tables django orm

Tags: django, orm

I have models

```
class Trpinjaman(models.Model):

    uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='uid', )
    cjenispinjaman = models.CharField(db_column='cJenisPinjaman', max_length=255, blank=True,
                                  null=True)

class Trpinangsuran(models.Model):
   cbulan = models.CharField(db_column='cBulan', max_length=6, blank=False, null=True)
   cpinjamanid = models.ForeignKey('Trpinjaman', db_column='cPinjamanId', blank=True,
                                null=True)
   ccicilanke = models.IntegerField(db_column='cCicilanKe', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to display all data from both models using this code

```
datapinjam=Trpinjaman.objects.all()
for obj in datapinjam:
        obj.uid,
        obj.jenispinjaman,
        obj.cbulan,
        obj.ccicilanke,
```

but i get this error

```
'Trpinjaman' object has no attribute 'cbulan'
```

Comment: Are you sure there is exactly one **Trpinangsuran** object for each **Trpinjaman** object? If not do you want to show fields of each **Trpinangsuran** object related to one **Trpinjaman** object?

Comment: I can't do that. But Trpinangsuran has field cpinjamanid that foreignkey to Trpinjaman, i guess it can retrieve all data from Trpinangsuran.

Comment: It would be easier if your variable names were in English. You shouldn't use `id` in your model and you don't need to define the db_column. `cpinjaman` instead of `cpinjamanid`. Also since it's a foreign key to `Trpinjaman` why isn't it called `trpinjaman`?

Comment: yes that's true, but i use mysql. I didn't use makemigrations and migrate to generate the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options-

**1)** Since you are using ForeignKey, there may be multiple **Trpinangsuran** objects for each **Trpinjaman** object, hence you'll have to decide which one of those multiple objects to use. One way is taking the first **Trpinangsuran** object for each **Trpinjaman** object. You can do following-

```
datapinjam=Trpinjaman.objects.all()
for obj in datapinjam:
    obj.uid,
    obj.cjenispinjaman,
    trpinangsuran_obj = obj.trpinangsuran_set.first()
    trpinangsuran_obj.cbulan,
    trpinangsuran_obj.ccicilanke,
```

-- You can also use order_by ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)) to decide on what basis you want to take the first.

**2)** If you are sure there will always be one **Trpinangsuran** object for each **Trpinjaman** object, I'll recommend using  [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) instead of ForeignKey. Then it'll be something like this-

```
datapinjam=Trpinjaman.objects.all()
for obj in datapinjam:
    obj.uid,
    obj.cjenispinjaman,
    obj.trpinangsuran.cbulan,
    obj.trpinangsuran.ccicilanke,
```

Hope it helps, also please go through django queryset [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: Thank you @Saurabh Goyal. It has solved. I use 
obj.trpinangsuran_set.first().ccicilanke

Answer (score 0):

cbulan is part of the Trpinangsuran model.  By doing:

datapinjam=Trpinjaman.objects.all()

you only get objects of the Trpinjaman type whose only fields are uid and cjenispinjaman.

To show all elements of both models you need to do a loop over all elements of Trpinangsuran and all elements of Trpinjaman

Comment: i want to export data to xls format, and join two models in one table.